# iOS UI Automation with a lot of scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, instruments, ui-automation

I have spent the past week tweaking a Xcode/Instruments/UIAutomation script trying to get what should be easy automation to work. But nothing works as I would expect it to.

From what I can tell, this is due to the way that controls are virtualized when they are off-screen. The problem is that the vast majority of what I need to test at any given time will not be rendered until I explicitly scroll to it.

Specifically, I have a UIAScrollView with two pages. The second page has a collection with a huge number of cells, as well as StaticText occasionally.

I haven't found a good way to validate that the StaticText are displaying what they should. The only way I have found is to look at the StaticTexts currently onscreen, scroll a small amount, see if it changed, and keep doing that. This is problematic, particularly because I eventually get to the bottom and there's no explicit way to tell I'm done scrolling.

I have tried finding elements by name and using scrollToVisible... this seems to work if the control in question is "just" off screen, but only then.

Is there any workaround for this besides having a loop which does a small amount of scrolling repeatedly until it sees the control it is looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the length of the cells array and loop through it. One way to do it is:

```
for (var index = 0; index < mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].cells().length; index++)
{
    var currentCell = mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].cells()[index];
    mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].scrollToElementWithName(currentCell.name());

    //Do whatever you need to do
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first check is it valid or not than check for is visible refer following....

```
if ( window.staticTexts()["YourStaticText"].checkIsValid() )
{
if (!window.staticTexts()["YourStaticText"].isVisible() )
{
    UIALogger.logMessage("object is valid");
    window.staticTexts()["YourStaticText"].scrollToVisible();

}
}
```

and if you want to scroll it for next page

```
window.staticTexts()["YourStaticText"].scrollDown();
```